# Some numbers are skipped in counting number of values greater and less than certain values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm having problems with counting the number of values greater than `start` *(initially 0)* and less than `end` *(initially 10)* certain values in a list.

The list contains 12 500 ***float numbers*** from the range 0 - 110. I want to count how many numbers out of the list are in the range 0-10, then 10-20, 20-30, (...), 100-110

I have implemented a for loop with a list comprehension inside like that:

```
all_nums = [] # contains 12_500 float numbers

nums_counted = []
start = 0
end = 10
for x in range(11):
    count = len([x for x in to_int if start < x < end])
    nums_counted.append(count)
    start = start + 10
    end = end + 10
```

The problem is `len(all_nums) = 12500` and `sum(nums_counted) = 12492`, which should be equal to 12 500 as well.

I do not know what am I doing wrong and where those 8 numbers disappear

Comment: I'm guessing those are the 0s, 10s, 20s, etc since those never get counted towards any category. You'll probably want to change one of the `<` to be a `<=`. Also, you really shouldn't be iterating over the entire list every single time, you can achieve your goal with one single pass over the list, which is far more efficient

Comment: Ahh yeah, so straightforward. Thanks Lukas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do int division by 10

```
> from collections import Counter
> 
> l = [0.0, 0.1, 6.1, 11.4, 19.2, 20.9, 40.1]
> 
> d = Counter()
> 
> for val in l:
>     binn = val//10
>     d[binn] += 1
> 
> print(l) 
> print(d.items())
[0.0, 0.1, 6.1, 11.4, 19.2, 20.9, 40.1]
dict_items([(0.0, 3), (1.0, 2), (2.0, 1), (4.0, 1)])
```

In this case 0.0 --> 0-10 range which has 3 count